# VBA help in selecting final row and choosing range

Tags: excel, vba

The following code is doing the following:

1. Starting from A1, it searches for the last filled cell and selects
   the cell right after it.
2. After selecting the first available blank cell it selects the entire row
3. The entire row is then colored with color index 16.

Here you go:

```
Sub Macro1()

Range("A1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
With Selection.Interior
    .ColorIndex = 16
    End With
End Sub
```

This works great but I am having difficulty selecting only columns A to H within that row. I don't want to select the entire row.

Can someone please help me? I keep getting End With errors and not sure how to fix it :S

Thank you very much for your time and consideration!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is too much selecting! How about

```
Sub Macro1()
currentRow = Range("A1").end(xldown).offset(1,0).row
Range(cells(currentRow, 1), cells(currentRow,8)).Interior.ColorIndex = 16
cells(currentRow,1)= " "
End Sub
```

Does that work?

Comment: This will color the first blank row, which I suppose is wrong as you need to look at the last filled cell.

Comment: From what I can tell, this is precisely what the OP wanted. See point #2 in question.

Comment: @MattCremeens This works so well! Thank you! Can you help me with one more thing? Do you know how I can add a blank character in the first cell of that grayed out row? (Ax), I guess you can say. That way when I add more grey rows via macro, there won't be a conflict because that grey rows in the chart will have a blank character. Thank you!

Comment: @MattCremeens Beautiful! You've been an incredible help. Thank you!

Comment: @BMRobin Glad I could help. I've been helped countless times on this site. All the best to you.

Answer (score 1):

you can set a range for your selection, also here is another method to find last row from the end of the column (version 1) - the (Rows.Count,1) represents column A (Rows.Count,2) would represents column B and so on...

**this is version one: start looking for empty row from the end of column A:**

```
  Dim rowNum As Integer
    rowNum = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = Range(Cells(rowNum, 1), Cells(rowNum, 8))
    rng.Interior.ColorIndex = 16
```

**this is version two: start looking for empty row from the start (row 1) of column A:**

```
Dim rowNum As Integer
rowNum = Range("A1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).Row
Dim rng As Range
Set rng = Range(Cells(rowNum, 1), Cells(rowNum, 8))
rng.Interior.ColorIndex = 16
```

Comment: You can correct me if I'm wrong, but I believe the OP does not want the last row, but the first blank row.

Comment: changed Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row to Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1 now it will be the firs empty row

Comment: I don't think so. I think that'll just give you the last empty row or the row below the last row.

Comment: maybe you are right...wrote 2 versions maybe somebodey will need someday to find the empty row from the end of the column

Comment: Thank you @jonathana! I appreciate you dual explanation. Very detailed.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
'Declare Variables
Dim rowNum as integer
Dim YourRange as range

'Find last row by counting cells not empty and adding 1
'Assumes that all cells from A1 down are filled. Change the +1 accordingly if not
rowNum = worksheetfunction.counta(activesheet.columns(1))+1

'Set range object to column A through H of your row number
Set YourRange = Activesheet.Range("A" & rowNum & ":H" & rowNum)

'Set interior color of the rnage object instead of using Selection
YourRange.interior.colorindex=16
```

Comment: Thank you @asp8811. I like how you use declare variables. Very logical.

Comment: You're welcome. I missed a couple of apostrophes in my code comments, so check back to see the corrections if you didn't notice them.